# Could a hard disk filled with data slightly heavier then empty disk?

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How much does a gigabyte worth of data physically weigh on a hard disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/11423/how-much-does-a-gigabyte-weigh-on-a-hard-disk)

And the same question on CD-ROM, floppy disk and Flash drives?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/11423/how-much-does-a-gigabyte-weigh-on-a-hard-disk

Comment: Perhaps a gigamount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The data on a HDD is stored in bits.  These bits are essentially magnetic switches that are ether at 0 or 1. so there is no weight loss or gain each time data is written because the switch doesn't move, just the position.

For a CD, essentially a laser change the color of the CD track, almost like a switch being changed from a 0 to a 1.  However because in the majority of cases this is done through a process of burning, the effect is irreversible.

I don't know about floppy disks.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think so, given that hard drives simply rely on a pattern of magnetization to store the data. As data is not physically transferred to the platters, the drive cannot increase in mass. The same goes for CD-ROM, floppy disks, and flash drives.

Comment: @DragonLord But where would the mass go on a sealed CD-R for example?

Comment: @Dragonlord: the pits on mass-produced CDs are pressed - the matter is merely displaced, not removed. The "pits" on CD-RW are areas of alloy heated by high-power laser until they change from a reflective polycrystalline state to a darker amorphous state, no matter is removed.

Comment: I'm sorry for this mistake.  The comment relates to CD-R discs only.