# Does computer weight increase as I add data to my Hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive

I recently purchased a new Dell laptop. It weighs 1.34 KG. I want to add movies in my laptop. Will my laptop weight increase if I add movies?

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/11423/how-much-does-a-gigabyte-worth-of-data-physically-weigh-on-a-hard-disk

Comment: heh, not sure if this is a serious question - the linked question is close enough to be an answer. "Too little to bother" would be a practically accurate answer.

Comment: Yes, if you add the DVD's on top of the laptop. Same also applies with bricks, apples, badgers etc. The problem is of course trying to move with the laptop or open it with out this tower falling over...

Comment: @DaveRook: "The problem is of course trying to move with the laptop or open it with out this tower falling over..." If you have a badger on your laptop, coming close to it so that you can touch it will most likely already be a problem.

Comment: Well, the weight might increase if there are much heavy objects shown in the movies! :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Special Relativity tells us that energy has mass.  Therefore, the kinetic energy of the spinning disk platters will cause your HDD to gain mass when you switch it on.

This is probably more significant than any mass change you may have from the data stored.

Of course, the mass gain is still infinitesimally small.

Also, to be really pedantic, weight is the manifestation of mass in a gravitational field.  So, the weight will change if you carry the disk upstairs but the mass won't.

Comment: There is no part of this answer which isn't excellent!!! +1

Answer (score 18):

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Magnetic_recording) says

> An HDD records data by magnetizing a thin film of ferromagnetic
>   material on a disk.

Magnetizing material only changes the polarity/direction of the material's inner parts, it does not add or remove material.